# Use of s[i] - '0'

Tags: c++, char

The following code basically takes a string and converts it into an integer value. What I don't understand is why the `int digit = s[i] - '0';` is necessary. Why can't it work by using `int digit = s[i]` instead? What purpose does the `-'0'` have?

```
int main(){

    string s = "123";
    int answer = 0;
    bool is_negative = false;
    if (s[0] == '-')
    {
        is_negative = true;
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = s[0] == '-' ? 1 : 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        int digit = s[i] - '0';
        result = result * 10 + digit;
    }

    answer = is_negative ? -result : result;
    cout << answer << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Because the character `'0'` is coded as ASCII 48. So you need to subtract that to get digit values in the range `0..9`. However, there is no obligation to encode as ASCII, and the character `'0` might be encoded by some other value. But subtracting `'0'` itself rather than `48` will handle it.

Comment: `'0'` gives the code for the character, which is 48 in ASCII. Most encodings have the number codes in a sequence, so you can use this trick to convert a 1 digit integer into its character. I don't know if this property is guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: [How do you convert char numbers to decimal and back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529247/how-do-you-convert-char-numbers-to-decimal-and-back-or-convert-ascii-a-z-a)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in your question title

> the use of '0'

should be written as

> the use of `s[i] - '0'`

That said, by subtracting the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `char` 0 (represented as `'0'`), we get the `int` value of the digit represented in `char` format (ASCII value, mostly.)

Comment: Got it :)! Thankyou so much. 

Does this mean if add '0' to an integer i can obtain the char format back?

Comment: @MuneebRehman apparently, yes, but depends on what do you mean by  char format. If you're looking for the ASCII value, then certainly, yes.

Comment: @MuneebRehman If the integer is positive and less than 10.

Comment: @NeilKirk absolutely. A single digit non-negative int, shall we say? :)

Comment: Yes, actually my restriction was incorrect as 0 is also allowed!

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value inside s[i] is a `char` type.

To convert the char '1' into an integer, you do '1' - '0' to get 1. This is determined by position in the ASCII table, char '0' is 48, while char '1' is 49.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the subtraction is that `s[i]` is, for example, `'6'`. The value `'6'` evaluates to `54` (the ascii code). The ASCII code of '0' is 48. So `'6' - '0'` = 6, which is the char value expressed as an `int`.