# C++: Implicit conversion of int to char

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

In `C++`, char to int conversion is implicit but is int to char also implicit conversion?
for example,

```
int i = ..;
char c = ..;
i = c; // implicit, char to int
c = i; // implicit? int to char
```

Comment: There are varieties of implicit conversions: `char to int` is a `Numeric promotion` and `int to char` is a `Numeric conversion` both are `Implicit conversions`.  Have a read of: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529247/how-do-you-convert-char-numbers-to-decimal-and-back-or-convert-ascii-a-z-a

Comment: If it's a conversion, and it's not done explicitly via casting, then it's an implicit conversion I'd say.

Comment: @smac89: I certainly hope not! This is about int-to-char, not about  conversions of things similar to ascii.